# Is there a solution for encrypting data in DynamoDB for nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-dynamodb

I’m researching solutions for data encryption in dynamodb.
I found that there’s a library DynamoDB Encryption Client, but it’s only for Java/Python(our project is written in nodejs).
Also, there’s another package aws encryption SDK which works with AWS KMS.

The SDK can’t encrypt on table level. That means I have to traverse through all fields in an item and encrypt each one before storing it in DB. It doesn't seem to be a great idea.

Comment: All user data stored in Amazon DynamoDB is fully encrypted at rest. DynamoDB encryption at rest provides enhanced security by encrypting all your data at rest using encryption keys stored in AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS). Do you need another layer of encryption?

Comment: You're right it's encrypted at rest. But when you retrieve the data it' will be decrypted. I want to have application level encrypting solutions

Comment: Do you want to encrypt while your data travel out of the application?

Comment: AWS does provide JS based encryption SDK for data in transit. Did you check this out? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/js-examples.html

Comment: @Anil_M, yeah I checked that. But the issue is I need to encrypt dynamo table items with complex nested structure and not just plain text. Also I mentioned SDK in question

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you have to save the encrypted data in DynamoDB and encrypt/decrypt at application layer. Encryption for data from your application layer onwards is also your responsibility. AWS provides many services which helps us implement the security. So the dataflow will be something like:

```
Application(encrypt) -> DynamoDB
DynamoDB -> (decrypt) Application
```

Examples of encryption using Node (JS) using AWS KMS service can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/js-examples.html